# Serious performance issues with 7th gen Thinkpad X1 running Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, bios, thinkpad

I have been using various Thinkpad laptops with linux for development purposes for years. My recent model of choice is the X1. I've used the 4th and 5th gen with Ubuntu and they've been excellent for my needs in every way; they are/were fast and reliable.

Recently I switched to a 7th gen model and I'm devastated/gutted/heartbroken by the performance issues I'm experiencing.

```
Laptop - ThinkPad X1 7th gen

Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz

OS - Ubuntu 19.10 (tried 19.04/20.04 too)

Linux - 5.3.0-62-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 11:20:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This config I described is struggling with IntelliJ IDEA, the cursor is sometimes trailing, if I open up a new tab in Chrome, my maven/gradle build times suffer immensely. Sometimes videos on youtube fall back to 480p... I mean, something's seriously wrong.

Ran a bios diagnostics check on the hw itself and didn't flag any problem with my cpu/memory/other hw.

I tried messing with cpu related power options in bios.
I tried enabling/disabling hyperthreading.
I tried installing some "lenovo fix" from github which let's you play around with pretty low level cpu settings and claims to help with performance if you set it up well.
I tried changing the governer profile to performance.
Still... nothing helped and I'm desperate to find the answer because I really don't want to switch from this config (X1 + Ubuntu).

If anyone has any idea what could be wrong or any suggestion it'd be gravely appreciated! Thanks!

Worth mentioning that my 5th gen, hooked to a type c docking station with 2 monitors was blazing fast, snappy, no issues whatsoever with performance.

Comment: I have a ThinkPad X1 4th generation with Windows 10 and it is very fast. I suggest calling Lenovo Support to see if they can help

Comment: I found the issue. My machine has a 2k display and I enabled fractional scaling in Gnome, which as it turns out has a massive performance hit. If one uses fractional scaling, they should be prepared for an unpleasant surprise...